# My table is putting one row's entries outside the table borders

Tags: tables

this is my first question here. I searched thoroughly, using search terms such as "latex tables data outside borders" and many permutations thereof, but no luck. I have a `\multicolumn` table, and one of the rows in the table is floating around outside the table, underneath the "Continued on Next Page" row.  Here is the code for the table, along with the rows in question:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{SOP X}
\doctype{SOP}
\docnumber{XX-XXXXX}
\supercedes{None}
\effectivedate{09/26/16}
\revisiondate{09/26/16}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

\section{Purpose}
\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|p{.25cm}|p{.25cm}|p{10.5cm}|}
\caption{Title of Table} \label{t:title_of_table}
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c} {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from Previous Page }} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{Continued on Next Page} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot 

\hline \fancyhead{}

\multirow{7}{\linewidth}{This Floats Outside the Table; Shd Be the 1st Column}  & \multirow{7}{\linewidth}{J} & 1 & This is in the 4th column; it shows up in the last row of the previous page, but the "This Floats Outside the Table" cell and the "{J}" cell make a second row, floating outside the page underneath the table \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 2 & This is OK, it shows up in the next page in the right column, where it should \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 3 & This is OK too \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 4 & This is OK too \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 5 & This is OK too \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 6 & This is OK too \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 7 & etc. \\ \hline
 \end{document}
```

Comment: please fix your example so people can run it to see any problem (I could guess some packages needed, but also the page size you are using may be relevant)

Comment: Thanks egreg!

Thanks David Carlisle, yes, there are some packages at the top; I have added them. However, there is a separate .cls document that adds the margins, and it also adds many things like headers with logos, etc., that I think would be too much (and might get into proprietary stuff).

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a group of rows in `longtable` together by using `\\*` instead of `\\`. The star form of `\\` ends the tabular without permitting a page break.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  hmargin=2cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{.85\textheight}

\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|p{.25cm}|p{.25cm}|p{10.5cm}|}

\caption{Title of Table} \label{t:title_of_table}

\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c} {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from Previous Page }} \\ \hline 

\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{Continued on Next Page} \\* \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot 

\hline


\multirow{7}{\linewidth}{This Floats Outside the Table; Shd Be the 1st Column}  & \multirow{7}{\linewidth}{J} & 1 & This is in the 4th column; it shows up in the last row of the previous page, but the "This Floats Outside the Table" cell and the "{J}" cell make a second row, floating outside the page underneath the table \\* \cline{3-4}

                   &                   & 2 & This is OK, it shows up in the next page in the right column, where it should \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 3 & This is OK too \\* \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 4 & This is OK too \\* \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 5 & This is OK too \\* \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 6 & This is OK too \\* \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 7 & etc. \\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The group of rows now goes to the second page.

Of course, large blocks of table rows or large rows make it hard for TeX to find good break points.

Comment: Sweet! Bam, problem solved. Appreciate it, Heiko, and have a great day!